# No gnome shell on xrandr new display

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, display, intel, xrandr

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 x86_64
Kernel: 5.11.0-36-generic
CPU: Intel Celeron B800 (2) @ 1.5GHz
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics

I forced xrandr to output into VGA-1 and it works but what doesn't is gnome in that display, I can move my mouse there, I can drag windows there but there's no background and nothing. It is also not detected by Gnome Settings.

I used `xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00 --right-of LVDS-1`

`xrandr` output is

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1366x768      59.99*+  40.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
   2560x1440_60.00  60.00  
   2432x1368_60.00  60.00  
   2176x1224_60.00  60.00  
   1920x1080_60.00  60.00  
   1664x936_60.00  60.00  
   1600x900_60.00  60.00  
   1536x864_60.00  60.00  
   1440x810_60.00  60.00  
VGA-1 disconnected 1920x1080+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080_60.00  60.00* 
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  a1920x1080_60.00 (0x161) 172.800MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2040 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock  67.08KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1081 end 1084 total 1118           clock  60.00Hz
```